# Runtime Complexity | Recursive calculation using Master's Theorem

Tags: recursion, mergesort, master-theorem

So I've encountered a case where I have 2 recursive calls - rather than one. I do know how to solve for one recursive call, but in this case I'm not sure whether I'm right or wrong.

I have the following problem:

T(n) = T(2n/5) + T(3n/5) + n

And I need to find the worst-case complexity for this.
 (FYI - It's some kind of augmented merge sort)

My feeling was to use the first equation from the Theorem, but I feel something is wrong with my idea. Any explanation on how to solve problems like this will be appreciated :)

Comment: I was able to solve this using recursion tree. Master's theorem just does not fit

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you did?

Comment: should I post the entire solution otherwise it will get messy in comments area.

Comment: Please, Go for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion tree for the given recursion will look like this:

```
                                Size                        Cost

                                 n                           n
                               /   \
                             2n/5   3n/5                     n
                           /   \     /    \
                       4n/25  6n/25  6n/25  9n/25            n

                         and so on till size of input becomes 1
```

The longes simple path from root to  a leaf would be n-> 3/5n -> (3/5) ^2 n .. till 1

```
 Therefore  let us assume the height of tree = k

            ((3/5) ^ k )*n = 1 meaning  k = log to the base 5/3 of n

 In worst case we expect that every level gives a cost of  n and hence 

        Total Cost = n * (log to the base 5/3 of n)

 However we must keep one thing in mind that ,our tree is not complete and therefore

 some levels near the bottom would be partially complete.

 But in asymptotic analysis we ignore such intricate details.

 Hence in worst Case Cost = n * (log to the base 5/3 of n)

          which  is O( n * log n )
```

Now, let us verify this using substitution method:

```
 T(n) =  O( n * log n)  iff T(n) < = dnlog(n) for some d>0

 Assuming this to be true:

 T(n) = T(2n/5) + T(3n/5) + n

      <= d(2n/5)log(2n/5) + d(3n/5)log(3n/5) + n

       = d*2n/5(log n  - log 5/2 )  + d*3n/5(log n  - log 5/3) + n

       = dnlog n  - d(2n/5)log 5/2 - d(3n/5)log 5/3  + n

       = dnlog n  - dn( 2/5(log 5/2)  -  3/5(log 5/3)) + n

       <= dnlog n

       as long as d >=  1/( 2/5(log 5/2)  -  3/5(log 5/3) )
```