# T(n) = c1T(n/a) + c2(T/b) + f(n)

Tags: recursion, iteration, time-complexity, master-theorem

Example T(n)=T(n/3)+T(n/4)+3n is this solvable with iterative master theorem or recursion tree.Can someone solve it analytically to show how it's done ?

Comment: Move to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can be done by a *binomial summation*, though whether analytically depends on form of `f(n)`

Answer (score 1):

We can expand `T(n)` with a *binomial summation*:

[image]

(after some steps - can be proven by induction

[image]

For some *depth of expansion / recursion* `k`.

Where do we terminate? When the parameters to *all instances* of `f(n)` reach a certain threshold `C`. Thus the maximum depth of expansion:

[image]

We choose the smallest between `a, b` because the parameter with only powers of `min(a, b)` *decreases at the slowest rate*:

[image]

Thus the general expression for `T(n)` is:

[image]

The existence of a closed form analytical solution depends on the form of `f(n)`. For the example provided:

[image]

The inner summation is the expansion of a binomial bracket raised to power `j`:

[image]

This is a geometric series, and equals (using standard formula):

[image]

Now since `7/12` is less than 1, the power term in the above result becomes *vanishingly* small for large values of `k` (and thus `n`). Therefore in the limit of large `n`:

[image]

Truth be told the above example could have been done more straightforwardly with a recursion tree; but the same does not go for e.g. other powers of `n`, e.g. `f(n) = Cn^2`, which can be trivially incorporated into the general formula.

Comment: So if 7/12 was greater than 1 time complexity would be O(nlogn) ? Also i tried doing this with recursion but the cost of each level is not  n like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032525/runtime-complexity-recursive-calculation-using-masters-theorem?rq=1 and I can't seem to find another example.

Comment: @user3638488 If *strictly greater* than 1 then it will not be `n log n` but some non-integer power of `n`. If *equal* to 1 then yes it will be `n log n` (as shown in the example, 2/5+3/5=1); you can see that from substituting into the series formula I gave - you will get `3n * km = 3n log n`