# How to solve a recurrence relation such as $T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + O(m)$

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I want to get the tighter bound for this recurrence in which we have two variables m and n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519), we can derive a *binomial summation* formula for `T(n)`:

[image]

Where

[image]

`C` is such that `n = C` is the stopping condition for `T(n)`.

---

In your specific example, the constants are: `c1 = 1, c2 = 1, a = 2, b = 4, f(n) = O(m)`. Since `O(m)` has no dependence on `n`, we can simply replace the `f` term with it.

[image]

How do we evaluate the inner sum? Recall the *binomial expansion* for integer powers:

[image]

Setting `a = b = 1` we get:

[image]

Thus:

[image]