# Solving the following recurrence: T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + sqrt(n)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, big-o

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + sqrt(n)
I currently have done the following but am not sure if I am on the right track:

1. T(n) <= 2T(n/2) +  sqrt(n)
2. T(n) <= 4T(n/4) +  sqrt(n/2) +  sqrt(n)
3. T(n) <= 8T(n/8) +  sqrt(n/4) +  sqrt(n/2) +  sqrt(n)
4. so, n/(2^k) = 1, and the sqrt portion simplifies to: (a(1-r^n))/(1-r)
5. K = log2(n) and the height is 2^k, so 2^(log2(n)) but:

   I am not sure how to combine the result of 2^(log2(n)) with the sqrt(n) portion.

Comment: Is the recurrence relation T(n) = 2T(n/2) + sqrt(n) or T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + sqrt(n) ?

Comment: It is T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + sqrt(n)

Answer (score 4):

A good initial attempt would be to identify the **upper** and **lower** bounds of the time complexity function. These are given by:

[image]

These two functions are much easier to solve for than `T(n)` itself. Consider the slightly more general function:

[image]

When do we stop recursing? We need a *stopping condition*. Since it is not given, we can assume it is `n = 1` without loss of generality (you'll hopefully see how). Therefore the number of terms, `m`, is given by:

[image]

Therefore we can obtain the lower and upper bounds for `T(n)`:

[image]

---

> Can we do better than this? i.e. obtain the *exact* relationship between `n` and `T(n)`?

From my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519), we can derive a *binomial summation* formula for `T(n)`:

[image]

Where

[image]

`C` is such that `n = C` is the stopping condition for `T(n)`. If not given, we can assume `C = 1` without loss of generality.

---

In your example, `f(n) = sqrt(n), c1 = c2 = 1, a = 3, b = 2`. Therefore:

[image]

---

How do we evaluate the inner sum? Consider the standard formula for a binomial expansion, with positive exponent `m`:

[image]

Thus we replace `x, y` with the corresponding values in the formula, and get:

[image]

Where we arrived at the last two steps with the standard geometric series formula and logarithm rules. Note that the exponent is consistent with the bounds we found before.

---

Some numerical tests to confirm the relationship:

```
N       T(N)
--------------------
500000  118537.6226
550000  121572.4712
600000  135160.4025
650000  141671.5369
700000  149696.4756
750000  165645.2079
800000  168368.1888
850000  181528.6266
900000  185899.2682
950000  191220.0292
1000000 204493.2952
```

Plot of `log T(N)` against `log N`:

[image]

The gradient of such a plot `m` is such that `T(N) ∝ N^m`, and we see that `m = 0.863`, which is quite close to the theoretical value of `0.861`.