# Algorithm time complexity using recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, proof

I have two questions about analyzing time complexity using recurrence relations.

**Question 1. How to form recurrence relations for an algorithm when using memoization? Is this even possible?**

For example consider computing the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence. The algorithm would be:

```
fib(n)
    if n < 2
        return n
    else
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

The recurrence relation for this piece of code is:

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c. The time complexity of this is roughly 2^n.

The memoized version of this code would be:

```
MemFib(n)
    if n < 2
        return n
    else
        if F[n] is undefined
            F[n] = MemFibo(n − 1) + MemFibo(n − 2)
        return F[n]
```

(Note: I took this from Jeff Erickson's notes which can be found here: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/. This algorithm is in chapter 5 - Dynamic Programming)

The complexity of this is O(n). I understand why this is O(n) because we are storing values in the table 'F' and performing lookups whenever possible however I do not know how to prove this mathematically.

Right now to me it looks like the recurrence relation is the same as the first example (T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c) which is obviously wrong. How would you write the recurrence relation of this? Is it even possible to write a relation for this because we do not perform recursive calls all the time? If it is not possible, how would you prove time complexity is O(n) formally?

**Question 2. How to analyze the complexity of algorithms which are in the following format:**

**T(n) = a*T(n/b) + c*T(n/d) + x?**

Here x is a constant.

Comment: To answer question 2, I have a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519). As a possible hint to question 1, the second recursive call is always constant time because the array has been filled up to 1 before or after it (note however the order of calls is undefined in many programming languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question**, the recurrence relation is not true any more because T(n) could have two values depending on if it has already been called or not (O(n) or O(1)).

A way to write the recurrence would be to differentiate first and second call :

```
Tf(n) = Tf(n-1) + Ts(n-2) + c = Tf(n-1) + O(1) + c = O(n).
```

**For the second question**, it is possible to extend the master theorem:

In your specific example with x = O(1):

```
T(n) = θ(n^γ) with γ such as a*(1/b)^γ + c*(1/d)^γ = 1
```