# Recurrence Relation 9-1 split

Tags: recursion, recurrence

Given the recurrence relation: $T(n)=T(9n/10)+T(n/10)+cn$, the recursion tree is given by [recurrence tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk3jk.png), how did they work out the longest path being $log_{10/9}n$?

Edit: unrelated, why does enclosing in dollar signs $, not format maths properly? Does that only work in the math part of stackoverflow?

Comment: 1) I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519) which will hopefully be what you want, 2) Stackoverflow devs deliberately omitted TeX support to speed up page loading, as equations are not seen as important on a programming  site

Comment: How did you get tex support in the answer you linked?

Comment: I simply uploaded images from an online TeX generator. I don't think there is a way of incorporating them into the title