# algorithm find O(n) with two T(n) on the other side of the recurrence equation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

next days I will have my exam on algorithms, the professor asked us to learn how to find O(n) of equations at this form:

`T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 5n`

`T(n) = T(n/3) + 2T(n/4) + 5n`

`T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 15n`

`T(n) = 2T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 4n`

I know how to use master theorem but I doubt I can use it somehow here. My professor also hasn't showed us even one example on how to solve this, on google I couldn't find much (or didn't know how to find a solution - how to search for it) so is it possible someone show me how to solve the aboves step by step?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry about the probably wrong title, as I said, I don't know how exactly to present what I want.

Comment: The usual approach is to observe that, for example, `T(n/3) >= T(n/4)` (although this isn't always true...). Then you can say that `T(n) >= 2T(n/3) + 5n`, and work from there. The `>=` is "okay", as you're still getting an upper bound on the function, even if it's not necessarily tight.

Comment: @hnefatl it should be `<=` instead of `>=` for `T(n)`. It is an upper bound.

Comment: I have a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519) which addresses functions of this kind. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, because `T(n/3) > T(n/4)` you can find an upper bound for each of the above equations (this condition is true for increasing `T(n)`).

`T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 5n => T(n) < 2T(n/3) + 5n =>(using master theorem) T(n) = O(n)`
Also, we can say `T(n) = \Theta(n)` as because of `5n` we can say `T(n) = \Omega(n)`.

`T(n) = T(n/3) + 2T(n/4) + 5n => T(n) < 3T(n/3) + 5n =>(using master theorem) T(n) = O(nlog(n))`

`T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 15n => T(n) < 2T(n/3) + 15n =>(using master theorem) T(n) = O(n)`

`T(n) = 2T(n/3) + T(n/4) + 4n => T(n) < 3T(n/3) + 4n =>(using master theorem) T(n) = O(nlog(n))`

Comment: I see, is there a case where T(n/3) > T(n/4) would evaluate to false though so this answer doesn't get accepted?

Comment: @PavTze as T(n) is increasing, so it is true.