# Recurrence: T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n^2 with tree methods

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, series

I'm trying to solve this exercise with tree method but I've a doubt about two parts: 
1) In the **T(?)** column, is it correct using (n^2/2^i) instead of (n/2^i)? I'm asking because this is the part which cause me the error;
2) Is the last multiplication correct (it's between the number of nodes and the time)? After finding the i value I have to create a serie which starts from 0 to the result of the multiplication, right? And as variable of the serie have I to use 2^i (the number of nodes)?
[image]

Comment: The `1/2^i` factor is also squared. Same for the 4. So the answer to 1 is no.

Comment: What about the multiplication?

Comment: That is correct for an *upper* bound, but you are neglecting / mixing the  `n / 4` terms.

Comment: As an aside, since the sum of `F_i/4^i` converges, the asymptotic complexity of this recurrence relation will be `n^2`. This may help you verify your answer.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong: (n^2/2^i) is right, but doesn't value for all the branches of the tree? How do I proceed? Because the part that cause me the error is that I don't know how to eliminate the n^2 to calculate the log.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424921/tn-c1tn-a-c2t-b-fn/45425519#45425519).

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to be using this method for this problem? There is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The column for the number of nodes is misleading.

Each node has a cost of `(m/k)^2` where `k` is whatever the denominator of the node is. With the structure you have using, the nodes in each level will have a variety of denominators. For example, your level 2 should contain the nodes [(m/16), (m/8)], [(m/8), (m/4)].

The cost for a level is the sum of the cost of each node in that level. Since each node has a different cost, you cannot multiply the number of nodes by a value to find the cost of a level, you have to add them up individually.

The total cost is the sum of the cost of each level. The result of this calculation may result in a logarithm, or it may not. It depends on the cost of each level and the number of levels.

*Hint: Pascal's Triangle*

Comment: The costs from the level 1 are always 3n/4. How can I setting up the serie?

Comment: My results are: #nodes=2^ i; T(?)= (n/2^i)^2; Costs= 3n/4

Comment: The main point of my answer is that you should not be counting the number of nodes. Your cost for level 1 should be (n/2)^2 + (n/4)^2